# Typecasting with unsigned and assignment to variable of different byte size

Tags: c, casting, unsigned, signed

Signed integer is assigned to an unsigned integer. Behaviour looks bit strange when using unsigned integer of different byte size.

Code 1:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef unsigned long   uint32;
    typedef unsigned short  uint16;
    typedef signed short    sint16;

    sint16 rawTCU = -100;

    int main()
    {
        uint32 _tmpSig = 0;
        _tmpSig = (uint32)rawTCU;
        printf("_tmpSig = %d",_tmpSig );
        return 0;
    }
```

Code 2:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef unsigned long   uint32;
    typedef unsigned short  uint16;
    typedef signed short    sint16;

    sint16 rawTCU = -100;

    int main()
    {
        uint16 _tmpSig = 0;
        _tmpSig = (uint16)rawTCU;
        printf("_tmpSig = %d",_tmpSig );
        return 0;
    }
```

Code 1 prints

```
    _tmpSig = -100
```

Code 2 prints

```
    _tmpSig = 65436
```

I don't understand how it behaves differently why different types cause to result in different values output. Why when used uint16 for assignment it creates a different value (which is equal to 65536 - 100 = 65436). How this gets optimized but not during usage of uint32. Please provide your suggestions how it works. Thanks!

Comment: If your compiler support it, please use the [standard fixed-sized integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) from `<stdint.h>` instead of making up your own.

Comment: Also, in the first snippet `_tmpSig` is a 32 (or 64) bit `unsigned long`. The `"%d"` format is for *signed* `int` (which is probably 32 bits). That's a mismatching format specifier and argument type, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

When a negative object of an signed integer type is assigned (or casted) to an unsigned integer type with a larger size then the sign bit is propagated.

In this expression

```
_tmpSig = (uint32)rawTCU;
```

the sign bit of the negative value of rawTCU is propagated to all 32 bits.

In this expression

```
_tmpSig = (uint16)rawTCU;
```

there is a truncation to 16 bits. The result of casting is considered as unsigned value. So neither propagation takes place.

Pay attention to that this call

```
printf("_tmpSig = %d",_tmpSig );
```

has undefined behavior. You have to write

```
printf("_tmpSig = %lu",_tmpSig );
                  ^^^
```

Comment: The C standard defines conversion to unsigned types in terms of the values involved. A C implementation will not convert by sign extension in (currently esoteric) one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude implementations.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is the implicit type conversion due to the integer promotion rules applied while passing arguments to `printf`.

You might have observed that you can print a `char`, `short int` or `long int` using the same format string **"%d"**. This is made possible by the fact that all optional arguments of `printf` undergo default argument promotion. In fact, this is the case with the arguments to **all variadic functions**!

A simplified sum-up of the promotion rules goes thus:

- Floats become double
- Integer types smaller than int (ie., chars and short ints) become int
- Unsigned int remains as unsigned int

This means that there is a hidden conversion here, which is not very obvious unless you look for it.

Case 1:

```
_tmpSig = (uint32)rawTCU;
```

Here, since we are converting **from a signed type**, sign-extension is performed so `_tmpSig` becomes a very large unsigned number, which is the representation of `-100`.

Now, when calling `printf`, no promotion happens since it is already an `unsigned int`. When printing,  since you have used "%d" formatting, it gets re-interpreted as a `signed int` and yields -100.

Case 2:

```
_tmpSig = (uint16)rawTCU;
```

After this, `_tmpSig` now holds an unsigned short int. No sign extension was required here because it was casted to a type of the same size. So there is no change in the representation at all.

However, when passed to `printf()`, it gets promoted to a `signed int`.
So here there is a hidden conversion from an `unsigned short` to a `signed long`. Since we are converting **from an unsigned type**, there is no sign extension here! This is where the value actually becomes **65436**. Now while printing as "%d", the same value is printed.

EDIT: Fixed a factual inaccuracy pointed out by @EricPostpischil

Comment: The C standard defines conversion to unsigned types in terms of the values involved, not as sign extensions. A C implementation will not convert by sign extension in (currently esoteric) one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude implementations.

Comment: Re “When printing, since you have used "%d" formatting, it gets converted back to signed int”: No, there is no conversion back to `int`. Per the C standard, the behavior of passing an `unsigned int` for formatting with `%d` is not defined by the standard. When an implementation proceeds with it, what typically happens is that the bits of the `unsigned int` are reinterpreted as, not converted to, an `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True Indeed. But I was trying to explain the behaviour the OP was seeing and had to assume a particular platform. A lot of the implicit assumptions taken here, such as short being narrower than int might not hold for every C language implementation. The key point is the integer promotion that happens while `printf()` is called which I felt no other answer had captured.

Comment: @EricPostpischil On your comment on "%d", I agree. I will see if I can rephrase this portion to make it more accurate.